# Jar permissions codebase for third party jars

Tags: java, swing, jnlp, java-web-start

I have an issue with my application after taking jre 7_25 version. My Java swing application is throwing permission and codebase required on console for third party jars.

For my swing jar I added permissions and codebase in manifest file but it is asking for third party jars as well. Is there any command or any option to fix this issue?

I saw in stack overflow there is a same question but he choose to extract the third party jars and add codebase and permissions in it. I cannot do this because I don't have access to my production server and I feel this is not a permanent solution.

I googled all day but no luck. Please give me some suggestions for this.

Comment: 1) Set the codebase in the JNLP 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson currently jnlp has codebase with proper url now i tried with codebase="*" then is not able to find jnlp file.

Comment: *"now i tried with codebase="*"  then is not able to find jnlp file.*  ..and that *surprises* you?  It seems you are attempting 'coding by magic'.  What is the JaNeLA report? Post it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17773273/edit).  Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.